# I installed Orchid on Laravel. Error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.".

Tags: laravel

I installed Orchid on Laravel. Did everything according to the instructions.
When I try to start the Orchid installation page, I get an error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.".
Help me fix it, I do not know what to do.
Thanks.

Comment: Set debug true and find what is the exact issue

Comment: Here's what debug found: /home/*/*/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#179 –

Comment: You have to add route

Answer (score 1):

There is a setup [DASHBOARD_DOMAIN](https://github.com/orchidsoftware/platform/blob/master/config/platform.php#L27) 
It is enough to install it, depending on which address you address.
By default, it is calculated based on [APP_DOMAIN](https://github.com/orchidsoftware/platform/blob/master/src/Platform/Support/helpers.php#L72)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
If you have the line API_DOMAIN or APP_DOMAIN in the ".env" file. Then leave an empty value that is "APP_DOMAIN ="